# Playcount for Media Files?

Tags: android, mp3, audio-player

I want to query meta data from the external storage. That's pretty straight forward with the [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). But I also want to get the play count of the mp3 file.

I looked into projects like [scrobble droid](http://code.google.com/p/scrobbledroid/) and [subsonic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/subsonic/) but I didn't find a way to retrieve the Play Count if it's there. (e.g. Winamp supports it.)

Is there a way to get the PC if it's there?

Answer (score 3):

You could manually read in the ID3 tags and check for a `playcount` attribute, but keep in mind, if this is for your own media player application, you'll have to modify the file each time it is played (load it, modify the ID3 tag, save the changes) which I imagine would be inefficient and a battery drain at best. Also, very few other media players actually DO this (Winamp, from what I see, seems to be one of the few), so it's not going to be an accurate playcount if played with, say, the stock media player, or any other media player which does not modify the ID3 tag.

Most media players that track playcounts (iTunes, Zune, etc.) do so by maintaining a database with playcount as an attribute. Obviously this is not portable between media players, but for your own implementation, I would suggest a database as your solution.

Comment: I don't want to write a media player. I want to scrobble the data and to know which music is favourized by the user I have to know how often he plays a song.

Comment: Then most likely you'll need to find a way to listen for media playback events and determine which track is playing (and when it finishes playing), which will probably be different for every media player.

Comment: Exactly and therefore I'm asking here on how to do it.

Comment: That's not exactly what your question is asking; likely there's not a stored playcount to RETRIEVE, but you might be able to intercept future plays and store that data for your application.

Comment: If anybody knows how to read available play DBs from some players please answer. Interception is a less-than-ideal solution which I have to implement also but I would like that to be a addition and not the main way of getting the playcount.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but found some solution. So, android does not provide the data but music players could store this info. What I did:
* decompiled music app
* grep manifest file looking for provider
* profit

The solution is not perfect but I think there is no other ways to get this information on not rooted device.